# Copying Rows from sheet to sheet in Excel VBA based upon column values

Tags: excel, vba

```
Dim LSearchRow As Integer
Dim LCopyToRow As Integer
Dim wks As Worksheet
On Error GoTo Err_Execute


For Each wks In Worksheets
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
    Set wksCopyTo = ActiveSheet
    wks.Rows(3).EntireRow.Copy wksCopyTo.Rows(3)

    'Start search in row 4
    LSearchRow = 4
    'Start copying data to row 2 in Sheet2 (row counter variable)
    LCopyToRow = 4

    While Len(wks.Range("A" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value) > 0
        'If value in column E = "Mail Box", copy entire row to Sheet2
        If wks.Range("AB" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value = "Yes" And wks.Range("AK" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value = "Yes" And wks.Range("BB" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value = "Y" Then
            'Select row in Sheet1 to copy
            wks.Rows(CStr(LSearchRow) & ":" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Select
            Selection.Copy
            MsgBox "Copying Row"
            'Paste row into Sheet2 in next row
            wksCopyTo.Select
            wksCopyTo.Rows(CStr(LCopyToRow) & ":" & CStr(LCopyToRow)).Select
            wksCopyTo.Paste
            MsgBox "Pasting Row"
            'Move counter to next row
            LCopyToRow = LCopyToRow + 1
            'Go back to Sheet1 to continue searching
            wks.Select
        End If
        LSearchRow = LSearchRow + 1
    Wend

    'Position on cell A3
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("A3").Select
    MsgBox "All matching data has been copied."
Next wks

Exit Sub
Err_Execute:
    MsgBox "An error occurred."
```

Hi

I have the above code which based upon from code given elsewhere. The code has been adapted where I need it to do to create a new worksheet for each existing worksheet when copying those rows that meet the criteria given in the if statement. The problem I have are:

1. Does excel allow you to find out first all the worksheets that exist before running the code so you don't go round in a loop?
2. The code I have given whilst working on one worksheet, will not execute after the while, and I cannot see why?
3. When I have run it on the one worksheet it crashes after 32,000 rows

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer your questions one by one:

1. Yes. You can use something like `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count` to return the number of worksheets the current workbook has. The best way to loop through worksheets however is to itterate through the `Worksheets` Collection:

   ```
   Dim wks As Worksheet

   For Each wks In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
       'Do something
       '...
   Next wks

   Set wks = Nothing
   ```
2. You are never exiting the loop (if you have >32,000 rows of data in Column A), until of course you get an Overflow error (Integers can only go to 32,767 +/-).
3. See point 2. You are looping beyond the limits of an Integer. Either change the data type to a Long and/or, as stated in point 2, exit your loop at some point.

Comment: Thanks! That will answers one of my questions, but I am still unable to understand why the rest of the code won't work and why on the other ocassion it crashes